# How to allow drupal/core-composer-scaffold to copy files in dev but not live site

Tags: composer

How can I have `drupal/core-composer-scaffold` behave differently when doing `composer install` on my live and my dev sites?

my live site's `sites/default` directory and its contents are write-protected. my dev site is not write-protected. I do not wish to copy *all* scaffolding files into the live site; but I do on the dev site.

The following is overkill as it prevents the latest scaffolding files being copied into the dev site as well as the live site.

```
"extra": {
        "drupal-scaffold": {
            "file-mapping": {
                "[web-root]/sites/default/default.services.yml": false,
                "[web-root]/sites/default/default.settings.php": false
            },
            "locations": {
                "web-root": "web/"
            }
        },
```